# How to make Unity's Dash save the results filtering?

Tags: unity-dash, lenses

The dash can remember the settings for filtered results for the entire session, but not beyond that. Once the profile is logged out and back in the results would reset to their original settings; displaying all the results without filtering. How can I make the results filtering more permanent? IE: How to make the photo lens for instance always show photos from "This Computer" and not from Picasa or Facebook across sessions and not just temporarily?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/393569/making-unity-dash-filters-stick has find solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can. These seems to be stored in memory only and lost every time the service is restarted.

You could however uninstall scopes that you do not want to use. You could also disable "remote" scopes by going to system settings, privacy, and turning off "Include Online Search Results".

Failing that, you could always remove the .service files from /usr/share/dbus-1/services/

I STRONGLY recommend AGAINST doing that, but it is an option.

You can also file a feature request with the lense/scope maintainer.

I believe the ability to save previous seach results and filters would be done at the lense/scope level and not at a unity level. Though they may not be true.

TL;DR; You can't as of today.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/393569/making-unity-dash-filters-stick has find solution here

Answer (score 0):

`Unity Dash` -- Changing & making unity dash filters stick. Found these 3 methods online.

(1) `Open dash --> Click on Applications tab (on bottom of dash, second icon) --> Filter results --> Type --> Dash Plugins. Click on the individual plugin and select disable`

(2) How to disable the online results completely. This is done from within the System Settings tool. Simply follow these steps:
    Click the Super (or Windows) key on your keyboard
    Type Settings
    From the results, click the System Settings button
    Click on Security & Privacy
    Click the Search tab
    Click the On/Off button (Figure A) so that it changes to Off
    Close the System Settings

(3) As you might expect, you can also disable specific filters from the command line.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```