# making unity dash filters stick

Tags: unity, unity-dash

first time poster. I have deselected nearly all categories and sources in unity search filter but every time I type something new they are automatically re-enabled (music/amazon/ebay/lots more) I would like my filtering to be permanent (at least until the computer is shut down) as I do not require any of these results

I have searched my problem and not found an answer. I apologise if its already been covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to turn off Online Scopes in the Privacy Settings.
[image]

There is a list of the available scopes/lenses [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310709/which-scopes-are-available-in-the-default-ubuntu-installation), you should be able to remove them in software centre, or with `sudo apt-get remove...`.

Comment: Thank you I did this from the terminal. finally relevant search results!!!!!!!!!!!!!! do I just tick the answer as accepted?

Comment: Seems like you already have... :-)

Comment: Is this a bug, or was the dash designed to have dynamic filters that you can't set permanently while including Online sources? If the latter, then that's a rather big thorn-in-the-side to those who want to "set it and forget it" in regards to their search filters.

Comment: There have been questions like this in the past - e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/202944/how-to-make-unitys-dash-save-the-results-filtering - It sadly seems currently not possible, but might make an incredibly popular feature request.

Answer (score 5):

For 14.04: you can do this from the desktop.

Open dash --> Applications tab (on bottom of dash, second icon) --> Filter results --> Type --> Dash Plugins

Click on the plugin and select disable.

I learned this from:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/how-to-disable-amazon-shopping.html

Comment: wow!!!!! !!!!!! !!!!! I would never imagine that, is so NON-INTUITIVE... thx!!! :D, finally my dash app search is fast for the first time ever! I disabled the "Files & Folders" one!! :D